# php-word extension can you download

Tags: php, phpword

I'm thinking about integrating phpword extension in my website, but I researched its capabilities and I don't seem to see anything that involves automatic downloads. Can you download a doc using phpword extension?

Answer (score 1):

No you can't.... PHPWord is a library for **parsing** Word documents, for reading document files, creating new documentfiles; at its core, it provides tools for  editing their content; and for saving them (either to disk or to a browser).... that's its purpose.... and it's a pretty significant process to do that.

It is not written for retrieving files from remote sites.... that's up to any scripts that you write using the PHPWord library.

Comment: Any Suggestion of what i can use to parse and download word docs using php?

Comment: Write a little script to download the file yourself, then you can use PHPWord once you have it on your server's disk